# Return the row indices of df1 when those row values occur in df2 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, match

I'm coding in R. I have a big data frame (df1) and a little data frame (df2). df2 is a subset of df1, but in a random order. I need to know the row indices of df1 which occur in df2. All of the specific cell values have lots of duplicates. Tapirus terrestris shows up more than once, as does each ModType value. I tried experimenting with which() and grpl() but couldn't get my code to work.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  SpeciesName = c('Tapirus terrestris', 'Panthera onca', 'Leopardus tigrinus' , 'Leopardus tigrinus'),
  ModType   = c('ANN', 'GAM', 'GAM','RF'),
  Variable_scale = c('aspect_s2_sd', 'CHELSAbio1019_s3_sd','CHELSAbio1015_s4_sd','CHELSAbio1015_s4_sd')) 


df2 <- data.frame(
  SpeciesName = c('Tapirus terrestris', 'Leopardus tigrinus'),
  ModType   = c('ANN', 'RF'),
  Variable_scale = c('aspect_s2_sd', 'CHELSAbio1015_s4_sd'))
```

Should output an array: 1,4 because df1 rows 1 and 4 occur in df2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an index column in `df1` and `merge` the datasets.

```
df1$index <- 1:nrow(df1)
df3 <- merge(df1, df2)
df3$index
#[1] 4 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `match`.

```
df1[match(df2$SpeciesName, df1$SpeciesName), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(index = row_number()) %>%
    inner_join(df2)
```